# Get file size codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This gives a Warning Message: filesize(): stat failed for http://localhost/wft/uploads/4_Sat_Sep_10_2016_16_18_52.pdf

```
$file_path = base_url().'uploads/4_Sat_Sep_10_2016_16_18_52.pdf';
$size = filesize($file_path);
```

how to find file size of pdf.

Comment: Do the file really exists under "http://localhost/wft/uploads/4_Sat_Sep_10_2016_16_18_52.pdf"?

Comment: Yes file exists in uploads folder.

Comment: please try is_file($file_path) and is_readable($file_path) and post the response.

Comment: can you try  relative path

Comment: filesize('/var/www/html/files/Screenshot from 2016-09-09 10:01:44.png'); in ubuntu, don't add locahost

Comment: in relative path $size=filesize('../Screenshot from 2016-09-09 10:01:44.png');

Comment: Thank you @SharmaVikram. localhost not working.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without using the URI, instead using the path to the File.

```
<?php

    // CHANGE __DIR__ TO FIT WITH THE PATH TO THE ROOT DIRECTORY HOLDING THE PDF FILE
    $file_path = __DIR__ . '/uploads/4_Sat_Sep_10_2016_16_18_52.pdf';
    $size      = filesize($file_path);
```

Comment: Also, constant `FCPATH` can be used to indicate publicly available location `$file_path = FCPATH."uploads/4_Sat_Sep_10_2016_16_18_52.pdf";`

Comment: Right, as well, @Tpojka ;-)

Answer (score 0):

PHP `filesize()` function give the file size.

```
$path = "uploads/your_file";
$size = filesize($path);
```

NB: Path should be a relative path.